# Linker error LNK2001 unresolved external std::_String_base::_Xlen

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, static-libraries

> 1>ClCompile: 1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
>   1>libsphinx.lib(sphinx.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
>   symbol "public: static void __cdecl std::_String_base::_Xlen(void)"
>   (?_Xlen@_String_base@std@@SAXXZ) 1>libsphinx.lib(sphinx.obj) : error
>   LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl
>   std::_String_base::_Xran(void)" (?_Xran@_String_base@std@@SAXXZ)
>   1>C:\Users\shirokov_m\Documents\sphquery\Release\sphquery.exe : fatal
>   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals 1> 1>Build FAILED. 1> 1>Time
>   Elapsed 00:00:00.25
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I hadn't any problems with libsphinx.lib compilation. Then I created a new project ( sphquery ) and linked the library to it. Now I have LNK2001 error.

Comment: It looks like you're not linking the C++ runtime library with your program. Unfortunately, I've no idea why not or how to fix it.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/60358e6a-2354-4c95-8d47-084fe8d1c76c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1182192/abhineet сказал верную мысль.