# Error: Unresolved external 'std::_String_base::_Xlen() const' referenced from-and others when compiling project in C++Builder11

Tags: c++builder-11-alexandria

As per title, I have 9 linker errors as follows:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::_String_base::_Xran() const' referenced from
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__InitExceptBlockLDTC' referenced from 
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::_String_base::_Xlen() const' referenced from 
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_ReThrowException(unsigned int, unsigned char *)' referenced from 
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_CatchCleanup()' referenced from 
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall __DynamicCastVCLptr(void *, void *)' referenced from 
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_ThrowExceptionLDTC(void *, void *, void *, void *, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned char *, void *)' referenced from 
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__Return_unwind' referenced from
```

These references refer to custom components written in C++Builder 10.1, 10.2 Berlin, and compile and used in projects without too much fuss.

The unfortunate thing about this is that I have not come across any real solutions for this in reference to C++Builder, found here: [Linker error LNK2001 unresolved external std::_String_base::_Xlen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085002/).

When I loaded the project into C++Builder 10.4, installed just today, apart from a couple of migration errors corrected quickly, the components installed into the component pallet but linker errors occurred when compiling the project that uses the components.

I have searched for any reference to the linker error, maybe I am using the wrong search engine, I will not use Google so, any pointing in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

I tried searching for solutions by asking questions in the search engines, no useful answers were found, with little to no detailed in C++Builder (not unusual), so I came here to ask the experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here to help others.

A thought crossed my mind, so I checked the compiler version, `Use 'Classic' Borland compiler` was unchecked, when I checked the option and re-compiled, it ran without issue.